# Using (react-router Link) and (react-draggable-core) together, makes improper dragging

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using both `react-router` Link and `react-draggable` in a nested structure. The problem is that when I want to drag my icon(here GlyphShow) by clicking on it, instead of dragging the icon, the link reference text(newAddress) is shown near the mouse pointer and the drag and drop process crashes.

In other words, I have an icon that I want it to be `draggable`, and also when it is clicked, navigates me to a new url(newAddress) :

```
import {DraggableCore} from 'react-draggable';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
.
.
.
<Link to='/newAddress'> <GlyphShow fontAwsome='user'/> </Link>
```

I used `react-draggable` component in my GlyphShow :

```
<Draggable><div className="GlyphShowClass"><FontAwsomeIcon className='glyph' icon={props.fontAwsome} /></div></Draggable>
```

Does anybody have an suggestion to use these together without problem?

Thanks in advance!